# How to code that two images touches each other?

Tags: android

I'm new to android. i'm making a game in which if two image touch each other the points are gained. now i don't know how to find that how to code it. can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use the Canvas class to draw your bitmaps they all need to be placed inside a rectangle on the screen. The [rectangle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) class has the methods intersects and [contains](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#contains(android.graphics.Rect)).

The first will return true if any parts of the two rectangle intersect. The second will return true if the rectangle performing the method contains the one passed.